# How to filter Table Row using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Good day everyone! Can somebody help me regarding to my problem? The filter code is from w3school. My problem is when I put the exact name or age in the `textbox`. There is no row show. All the row is gone except to my `thead`. I want to remove and show the table row defends to the name or age I input in my textbox. I'm using jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $("#tblBody tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<br><br>
  <button id="btnAdd">New</button>
  <table id="tblData" border = "1px">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tblBody">
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    var id = 1;
    $(function() {
      $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
      $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
      $("#btnAdd").bind("click", Add);
    });

    function Add() {
      $("#tblBody").append(
        "<tr>" +
        "<td>" + id + "</td>" + 
        "<td><input type='text'></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text'></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text'></td>" +
        "<td><button class='btnSave'>Save</button><button class='btnEdit'>Edit</button><button class='btnDelete'>Delete</button></td>" +
        "</tr>");

      $('#r2').hide();

      $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
      $('.btnEdit').attr('disabled','disabled');
      $('.btnDelete').attr('disabled','disabled');

      $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
      $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
      $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
      id++;
    };

    function Save() {

      var par = $(this).parent().parent(); 
      var tdFirstName = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
      var tdLastName = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
      var tdAge = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
      var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(5)");

      tdFirstName.html(tdFirstName.children("input[type=text]").val());
      tdLastName.html(tdLastName.children("input[type=text]").val());
      tdAge.html(tdAge.children("input[type=text]").val());

      tdFirstName.html("<input type='text' id='txtName' value='" + tdFirstName.html() + "'/>");
      tdLastName.html("<input type='text' id='txtPhone' value='" + tdLastName.html() + "'/>");
      tdAge.html("<input type='text' id='txtEmail' value='" + tdAge.html() + "'/>");

        $('#btnAdd').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.btnSave').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('.btnEdit').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.btnDelete').removeAttr('disabled');

        tdFirstName.find('input').attr('disabled', 'true');
          tdLastName.find('input').attr('disabled', 'true');
          tdAge.find('input').attr('disabled', 'true');

      //$(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
      $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
      $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);

    };

    function Edit() {
      var par = $(this).parent().parent(); 
      var tdFirstName = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
      var tdLastName = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
      var tdAge = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
      var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(5)");

      tdFirstName.val("<input type='text' id='txtName' value='" + tdFirstName.html() + "'/>");
      tdLastName.val("<input type='text' id='txtPhone' value='" + tdLastName.html() + "'/>");
      tdAge.val("<input type='text' id='txtEmail' value='" + tdAge.html() + "'/>");

      $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
      $('.btnEdit').attr('disabled','disabled');
      $('.btnSave').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.btnDelete').removeAttr('disabled');

      $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
      $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
      $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);

      tdFirstName.find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
      tdLastName.find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
      tdAge.find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
    };

    function Delete() {
      var par = $(this).parent().parent(); 
      par.remove();
      id = 1;
    };

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its working fine what was the issue?

Comment: no row show when I search for a firstName or lastName

Comment: where is your `first name and last name` data in table there is no any data

Comment: I used add function to create a table row using jQuery.

Comment: where is `add function` call in your code provide full code for better answer

Comment: Ok sir I already include all the codes above

Answer (score 0):

try this one

instead of `#tblBody tr` use `#tblBody tr input` where you want to search.and `use`val()`instead of`text()` so it will work

```
$("#tblBody tr input").filter(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
});
```

//Remove row when no match found try this code

```
if($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1){
     $(this).closest('tr').show();
     // $(this).toggle($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
}else{
     $(this).closest('tr').hide();
}
```

Comment: It is possible that the `row` will be remove if didn't match to value I input in the `textbox`? I want to remove the row and show only the the row that match to the textbox